# Monte Carlo integration to solve coefficients of an orthogonal series - reusing the set of random points

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials, monte-carlo

I'm trying to approximate a function by summing a series of orthogonal functions.

$f(x) \approx \sum_i a_i \phi_i(x)$

Since the set of functions $\phi_i(x)$ are orthogonal with respect to each other, I can directly solve for each coefficient $a_i$.

However, this involves solving an integral which I can't solve analytically:
$\int f(x)\phi_i(x) dx$

I've opted to use simple Monte Carlo integration to approximately solve the integral.

**My Question**

For each coefficient I want to solve, I have to generate some set of randomly-chosen points for each Monte Carlo integration. Would it improve my approximation of $f(x)$ if I re-used the same set of random points for each of the integrations?

My thinking is that the solution of each individual term in $a_i$ is only an exact solution in the context of all other terms in the series. I'm worried that the random fluctuations in the estimates for each term will increase the overall error of the approximation a lot.

Comment: A couple of comments. i) Re-using the set of random points may speed-up your code (slightly), but may have a catastrophic effect on the accuracy of your computation. Imagine you're integrating over the interval $x\in [-1,1]$ and you consider two functions $\phi_1(x)$ and $\phi_2(x)$, one extremely peaked around $+1/2$ and the other around $-1/2$. Using the same set of 'random' points for the two integrations might well be a terrible idea (the whole point of a Monte Carlo is to have a much finer mesh around the regions where your integral picks its largest contribution, which of course may....

Comment: ...vary *a lot* depending on your integrands. ii) I am not sure if you have other reasons for wanting/needing to use a Monte Carlo, but how about a Gauss-Legendre quadrature instead? You may fix the number of nodes $n$ and the corresponding abscissas once and for all, and you only need to compute a handful of sums...if your functions $f(x)$ and $\phi_i(x)$ are reasonably well-behaved, you don't normally need to go too high in $n$...

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo Well, at this point I'm not yet using any kind of weighting or special distribution to choose random points from. I suppose introducing that weighting would be a much more surefire way to improve the accuracy of the computation? As for why I chose MC, the domain that I'm integrating over is 6-dimensional, so I figured quadrature would be a bit labor-intensive.